# Convert number input to characters in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How to convert a number entered in google sheets to some characters?

Example:

- input in cell: “1234”
- output format in cell: “ABCD”

So I’d like to have some logic that will loop through every digit and convert it to a corresponding **character of my choice**, and have that be what is displayed in the cell.

**EDIT:** The character <> number representation don't have to be sequential. So we could have 1:"A", 2:"Q", 3:"E" etc. And the conversion should happen in place then replace the input altogether, as if the string was entered initially and not the numbers. Not sure if that can be achieved without a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You'll need a script

You can take advantage of an `onEdit` trigger. This is something that allows a script to run every single time there is an edit on your sheet. Within the trigger, you can tell it to replace the contents of a cell if it meets certain criteria. For instance, if its in a certain range, or it contains a certain value.

#### Example:

```js
const code = {
  'A': 1,
  'B': 2,
  'C': 5,
  'D': 6,
  'E': 9,
  'F': 8,
  'G': 7,
  'H': 3,
  'I': 2,
  'J': 45,
  'K': 4,
  'L': 32,
  'M': 45,
  'N': 5,
  'O': 4,
  'P': 3,
  'Q': 6,
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnEnd === 1 &&
      e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    let letters = e.value.split("")
    let numbers = letters.map(letter => code[letter])
    let newValue = numbers.join("")
    e.range.setValue(newValue)
  }
}
```

Within the `code` dictionary, you need to define what you want the conversion to be.

Then within the `onEdit` function:

- It checks if the change is in the first column.
- If so, it takes the value (`e.value`) and splits it into an array. So if the value input into the cell was `"ABC"` then the resulting array would be `["A","B","C"]`.
- Then it `map` the array using the `code`. This just goes through the array and returns whatever is in the dictionary. So now you have `[1,2,5]`.
- Then it `join` the resulting array into a continuous string `"125"`
- Finally, it `setValue` using the `e.range` to the `newValue`.

#### Room for improvement

- You need to make sure you have all the possible characters that someone will enter within the `code` object. Or you will need to handle the case of what to do with a character that is not in the object. For example, you could just return a space:

  ```js
  let numbers = letters.map(letter => {
        if (code.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
          return code[letter]
        } else {
          return " "
        }
  ```
- You may have an issue with converting numbers to letters. Seeing as there are only 10 single digit numbers (0 - 9). For example, if you have A = 1 and B = 11. If the value in a cell was converted to `11` then you wouldn't know if the original value had been `AA` or `B`.

#### References and further reading

- [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit())
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/attribute#setValue(String))
- [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(JOIN(, CHAR(64+REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", JOIN("|", REPT("(.)", LEN(A1)))))))
```

[image]

---

suggested approach:

```
=INDEX(JOIN(, CHAR(64+SPLIT(A3, " "))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have explained further in my question that the character <> number representation don't have to be sequential. So 1:A, 2:Q, 3:E etc. Will edit my question.